# Trigger cloud function on sub-collections update

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I know that this question is already asked but it didn't help.
I have a "chats" collection with one document "members" and a sub-collection "messages" and I would like to trigger a cloud function when a new message is added in the sub-collection.

This is what I tried but it is only triggered when "members" is updated, and does not have any information on the sub-collection:

```
exports.chatsCollectionTriggers = functions.firestore.document('/chats/{chatId}/messages/{messageId}').onUpdate(async (change, context) => {

let chatBefore = change.before.data();
let chatAfter = change.after.data();

console.log(JSON.stringify(chatBefore, null, 2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(chatAfter, null, 2));

console.log(context.params.chatId);
console.log(context.params.messageId);});
```

My firestore collection :
[image]

My question is how can I trigger a cloud function on a sub-collection update ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your Cloud Function will not be triggered when you modify a document of the `chats` collection (e.g. if you modify the `members` field of the `G162R...` document).

Your Cloud Function will be triggered when you **modify** (not when you create) a document in the `messages` subcollection of a document in the `chats` collection. For example, if you change the value of the `text` field of the message document `vVwQXt....`.

---

So, to answer to your question

> My question is how can I trigger a cloud function on a sub-collection
> update

If by "sub-collection update" you mean the **update** of an existing document in a subcollection, your Cloud Function is correct.

If by "sub-collection update" you mean the **creation** of a **new** document in a subcollection (which can be one interpretation of "a sub-collection update"), you should change your trigger type from `onUpdate()` to `onCreate()`.

From the following sentence in your question, i.e. "I would like to trigger a cloud function **when a new message is added** in the sub-collection", it seems you want to go for the second case, so you should adapt you Cloud Function as follows:

```
exports.chatsCollectionTriggers = functions.firestore.document('/chats/{chatId}/messages/{messageId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

    const newValue = snap.data();

    console.log(newValue);

    console.log(context.params.chatId);
    console.log(context.params.messageId);

    return null;   // Important, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions

})
```

---

More details in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?authuser=0#wildcards-parameters).

Comment: Very clear explanations, thank you it worked for me !